# Is or was `begin` a keyword in C? What does `begin` mean in this code snippet?

Tags: c

I am looking at a C program from 1986 ([ESPRESSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer) by R. Rudell). The function `espresso` begins as follows:

```
pcover espresso(F, D1, R)
pcover F, D1, R;
{
    pcover E, D, Fsave;
    pset last, p;
    cost_t cost, best_cost;

begin:
    Fsave = ...
    ...
...
}
```

What's the meaning of `begin`? I've never seen it before. Vim highlights it as a keyword.

Comment: It's a label, not a keyword.  Somewhere else in the same function should be a statement `goto begin;` (possibly several of them).  If there isn't, the label is pointless.  I note that the function is defined using the K&R (pre-C90 standard) notation.  You should not be using such function definitions yourself.  However, if the book is from 1986, it is 100% excused; the standard was not available until 1989 at earliest.  Be cautious though — pre-standard C is a rough, wild countryside, and the book will probably espouse techniques that are no longer a good idea.

Comment: See also [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) for a discussion from the early days of SO.  There is useful information in amongst the answers.